# Error during installation - Database initialization failed

Tags: mysql, server

During the final step of the installation of MySQLServer (Apply Configurations), I get a strange error. I can't get it. Here's the Log :

```
Attempting to add a Windows Firewall rule with command: netsh.exe advfirewall firewall add rule name="Port 3306" protocol=TCP localport=3306 dir=in action=allow
Ok.


Successfully added the Windows Firewall rule.
Ended configuration step: Updating Windows Firewall rules

Beginning configuration step: Adjusting Windows service
Attempting to grant Network Service require filesystem permissions.
Granted permissions.
Adding new service
New service added
Ended configuration step: Adjusting Windows service

Beginning configuration step: Initializing Database
Attempting to run MySQL Server with --initialize-insecure option...
Starting process for MySQL Server 8.0.11...
Starting process with command: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini" --console --initialize-insecure=on...
2018-06-25T21:06:16.705865Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011071] [Server] Unknown suffix '.' used for variable 'lower_case_table_names' (value '0.0')
2018-06-25T21:06:16.706023Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011071] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Error while setting value '0.0' to 'lower_case_table_names'
2018-06-25T21:06:16.706780Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2018-06-25T21:06:16.707053Z 0 [Note] [MY-010120] [Server] Binlog end
Process for mysqld, with ID 6372, was run successfully and exited with code 1.
Failed to start process for MySQL Server 8.0.11.
Database initialization failed.
Ended configuration step: Initializing Database
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what worked for me : I uninstalled everything, re-download the installer, updated it, and it worked finally! Weird error..

Answer (score 1):

Just had this same problem, i don't know what caused Database initialization failed. 
But the error was gone after 
i did a complete uninstall with 'MySQL Installer - Community', restart my pc and then tried to install mysql server.

Comment: Don't know either, I personnaly uninstalled everything, re-download the installer, updated it, and it worked finally!

Answer (score 0):

What seemed to work for us, is during installation, when you are prompted to upgrade your installer, select YES.

Answer (score -4):

I run a development system and beta production system on two separate machines.  My production system went down on Sunday/Monday.  Ended up doing a full re-install to get it going again.  Today my development system went down after a server restart.

I found the last line in the file "my.ini" (located with the data) was causing the error  "lower_case_table_names=0.0" is an invalid setting.  Changed that to 1 for Windows, and then I was able to restart the server without any other changes.  I hate fixes like that, who changed that setting?

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?