# the configuration for mysql has failed?

Tags: mysql, database

```
Beginning configuration step: Writing configuration file
Ended configuration step: Writing configuration file

Beginning configuration step: Updating Windows Firewall rules
Attempting to delete a Windows Firewall rule with command: netsh.exe advfirewall firewall delete rule name="Port 33086" protocol=TCP localport=33086

No rules match the specified criteria.


An error occurred running netsh.exe delete:
The netsh.exe process did not return any error. Review the application log to see if there is a trace of the error.
The attempt to delete a Windows Firewall rule failed.
You can add or delete a Windows Firewall rule manually by following the instructions at this URL:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Allow-a-program-to-communicate-through-Windows-Firewall
Adding a Windows Firewall rule for MYSQL80 on port 33060.
Attempting to add a Windows Firewall rule with command: netsh.exe advfirewall firewall add rule name="Port 33060" protocol=TCP localport=33060 dir=in action=allow
Ok.


Successfully added the Windows Firewall rule.
Ended configuration step: Updating Windows Firewall rules

Beginning configuration step: Adjusting Windows service
Attempting to grant Network Service require filesystem permissions.
Granted permissions.
Updating existing service
Existing service updated
Ended configuration step: Adjusting Windows service

Beginning configuration step: Initializing Database
Attempting to run MySQL Server with --initialize-insecure option...
Starting process for MySQL Server 8.0.11...
Starting process with command: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini" --console --initialize-insecure=on...
2018-06-29T03:19:19.775981Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011071] [Server] option 'read_buffer_size': unsigned value 0 adjusted to 8192
2018-06-29T03:19:19.776028Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011071] [Server] option 'read_rnd_buffer_size': unsigned value 0 adjusted to 1
2018-06-29T03:19:19.776087Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011071] [Server] Unknown suffix '.' used for variable 'lower_case_table_names' (value '0.0')
2018-06-29T03:19:19.776097Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011071] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Error while setting value '0.0' to 'lower_case_table_names'
2018-06-29T03:19:19.776900Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2018-06-29T03:19:19.777077Z 0 [Note] [MY-010120] [Server] Binlog end
Process for mysqld, with ID 3752, was run successfully and exited with code 1.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error during installation - Database initialization failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51031821/error-during-installation-database-initialization-failed)

Comment: ok i will try this I uninstalled everything, re-download the installer, updated it

Comment: doesn,t work ؟؟

Comment: Please post your complete (not edited) my.cnf-ini for analysis.

Comment: @Mahmoudlashin Please add to your Question your complete my.cnf or my.ini for analysis.  Current error log would also be helpful with date posted.  Is there any reason you are trying to use port 33086 and port 33060 rather than 3306?